# SAS Macro: Check a macro variable if value in a table

Tags: sas, sas-macro

I have two macro variables:

- `runasofdate` with value `'20190107'`
- `process_weekend` that will be either `'Y'` or `'N'`

Both macro variables are from an Excel config file and assigned using `call symput`.

Then I have a table with list of local holidays:

```
HOLIDAY_DESC  HOLIDAY_DATE
HOLIDAY1      20190101
HOLIDAY2      20190409
HOLIDAY3      20190418
HOLIDAY4      20190419
HOLIDAY5      20190501
```

I need help with coding a macro:

If &runasofdate is in the table HOLIDAY column HOLIDAY_DATE, then abort process 

Else if &runasofdate falls on a weekend and the macro process_weekend is in 'N' then abort process

Else if &runasofdate falls on a weekend and the process_weekend ='Y' then call sas programs (via %include)

Else if &runasofdate falls on a weekday then
call sas programs (via %include)

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to create a table that has all the dates and the Y/N flag in that table? And then if the record is a run date, run the code?

Comment: I only have like 22 rows in holiday.

Comment: How does that relate to what I said?

Comment: How many rows are in the Excel file ? What does the Excel table look like ? How many tabs, or how is the Excel data imported ?   Is the imported `RUNASOFDATE` value a string, number or a SAS date formatted value ? Is the `HOLIDAY_DATE` a string ? a number ? a SAS date value formatted as yymmdd10. ?  Show the CODE where you do `CALL SYMPUT`

Answer (score 0):

You haven't provided enough information to help you out fully but this can help you get started.

```
data have;
    set holiday_date end=eof;
    retain flag 'Run';
    *for this comparison to be valid - make sure you have the same types in the comparison;

    if holiday_date=&runasofdate then
        flag='Abort';

    if eof and flag='Run' then
        do;

            if weekday(&runasofdate) in (1, 7) and &process_weekend='Y' then
                do;
                    call execute ('sas program here');
                end;
            else if weekday(&runasofdate) not in (1, 7) and &process_weekend='N' then
                do;
                end;
            else
                do;
                    call execute('sas program here');
                end;
        end;
run;
```

The macro appendix has some examples of conditional logic. https://communities.sas.com/t5/SAS-Communities-Library/SAS-9-4-Macro-Language-Reference-Has-a-New-Appendix/ta-p/291716

Comment: I got an error:
 84                     if weekday(&runasofdate) in (1, 7) and &process_weekend='Y' then
                                                               _
                                                               22
 WARNING: Apparent symbolic reference PROCESS_WEEKEND not resolved.
 ERROR 22-322: Syntax error, expecting one of the following: a name, a quoted string, a numeric constant, a datetime constant, 
               a missing value, INPUT, PUT.

Comment: You said you had a process_weekend macro variable but the code isn't finding it. I'd be surprised if this worked - its the idea but you're going to have to customize it.